# How to bind enum values with SWT Combo

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to bind enum values to SWT Combo.

Lets says I am having following code snippet

**Person model class**

```java
public class Person {
 private String name;
 private Gender gender;

 public setGender(Gender gender) {
   this.gender = gender;
 }

 public Gender getGender() {
   return gender;
 }
}
```

**Gender enum**

```java
public enum Gender {
  MALE("male"), FEMALE("female");
}
```

**Binding between combo selection and gender property of Person.**

```java
IObservableValue<?> observeWidget = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(combo);                
IObservableValue<?> observeModel = PojoProperties.value(person.getClass(), "gender").observe(person);
```

**Binding between combo values and enum Gender.**

```java
IObservableList<?> observeWidget = WidgetProperties.items().observe(combo);
IObservableList<?> observableList = PojoProperties.list(enumGender.getClass(), "???? property name ????").observe(enumGender);
```

How i can achive above binding ??

I want to bind Gender.values() (this method default in every enum and return an array of string) with SWT combo.
For binding, we must provide property name in API call, but enum does not contain any such property.

I know we can achieve this using ComboBoxViewer like
comboViwer.setInput(Gender.values()). 
but I want to do bind any enum with combo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the snippet Snippet034:

> https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet034ComboViewerAndEnum.java

Basing on the version you are using maybe you have to adapt the call to "bindValue" passing less/more parameters

Comment: I have check that snippet they not used bindings for enum values and combo box. they just done gender.setInput(Gender.values());